# How not displaying horizontal scrollbar in Blazor base template

Tags: html, css, blazor-hybrid

So far I'm using the default Blazor Hybrid template and I have added a page with the following code.

html code

```
<div class="tableAntContainer">
<table class="tableAnt">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>A1</th>
            <th>A2</th>
            <th>A3</th>
            <th>A4</th>
            <th>A5</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>0.5</th>
            <th>0.85</th>
            <th>0.37</th>
            <th>0.7</th>
            <th>0.7</th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS is in a separate file is as follows:

```
.tableAntContainer{
border:3px solid red;
display:flex;
justify-content:center;
overflow-x:auto;
}

.tableAnt {
border: 1px solid black;
table-layout: fixed;
width: 500px;
}

.tableAnt th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align:center;
    width:100px;
}

.tableAnt td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align:center;
}
```

I get the following display.
[image]

But when I reduce the width of the window the horizontal scrollbar is displayed.
[image]

But instead I would like the scrollbar in the table.

If I reduce enough the width and go to column display I get the behaviour I would like in row display.

[image]

What do I have to change to get rid of the horizontal scrollbar in Row display mode?

Comment: Can you create fully working code sandbox?

Comment: How can I send a fully working code in Stackoverflow?

Comment: [stack-overflow-run-code-snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356678/stack-overflow-run-code-snippet)

Comment: Please find below a link to the test project.
https://github.com/Bert859/TestTables2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some additionnal research I found the solution to the issue.

Details are in the following other post:

[horizontal-scrollbar-in-div-doesnt-display-if-div-is-in-flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77835624/horizontal-scrollbar-in-div-doesnt-display-if-div-is-in-flexbox)

In Blazor one must edit the file MainLayout.razor.css and add in the main tag: min-width:0;
[image]

This is because the default setting for flexbox items is win-width: auto and therefore the item can not shrink smaller then the content.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting:

```
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.tableAntContainer {
  border: 3px solid red;
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

table {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Use margin to center the table since justify-content will cause some problems. Body's x axis scrollbar is hidden now. Should fix everything.

[Table with scrollbar (500% zoom)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JbBo.png)

[Table without scrollbar (100% zoom)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3q9pO.png)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but untotunatelys it doesn't work on my side.

Comment: I have started a new Blazor Hybrid projetct from scratch in order not to be fooled by some changes I may have made.
Adding body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
doesn't remove the horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: Quite strange, try removing either `table-layout: fixed;` or if you need that, try decreasing the width of `th`.

Comment: If you want to test it, here is a link to the project.
https://github.com/Bert859/TestTables2